# How to find rows updated in SQL Server during a particular instance

Tags: database, sql-server-2012

For example, I have a table with 1000 rows and 500 of them were updated last hour. The updated column has bool data type and is there a way to find out which of those 500 rows were updated. I don’t have any time stamp column in my table.

Comment: Practically speaking, no.  In the extreme there are ways that *might* work, but they are technically difficult and time consuming at best.  If it's really important, then the easiest way is probably to restore yesterday's backup of the database, to a new db on the same server and then compare then tables.

Comment: Appreciate your comment